# Recursive query where anchor and member have unions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, recursion

I'm trying to do a recursive query but the the anchor and member cte both have a union. Is this possible?  The error I get is

`Recursive member of a common table expression 'mainMenu' has multiple recursive references.`

The purpose of the union is allow the menu item to be visible by role or individual. If there is a better way of doing it I'm all ears. TIA!

```
with 
mainMenu (...)
as (
    select ...
    from (
        -- role
        select ...
        from ....
            and parentID is null
        UNION
        --user
        select ...
        from ....
            and parentID is null
    )as cteAnchor
UNION ALL
    select ...
    from (
        -- role
        select ...
        from ....
            inner join  mainMenu on parentID = mainMenu.id
        UNION
        -- user
        select ...
        from ....
            inner join  mainMenu on parentID = mainMenu.id
    )as cteChildren
)

select 
   ...
from 
mainMenu
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to `mainMenu` more than once. And this is caused by the fact that you actually have two anchor expressions, one for roles and one for users. There are two ways to fix this. You could split your query into two CTE's (one for roles, one for users). Like this:

```
with
roleMainMenu (...)
as
(
    -- role
    select ...
    from ....
        and parentID is null
    union all
    select ...
    from ....
        inner join  mainMenu on parentID = mainMenu.id
),
userMainMenu (...)
as
(
    -- user
    select ...
    from ....
        and parentID is null
    union all
    select ...
    from ....
        inner join  mainMenu on parentID = mainMenu.id
)
select * from roleMainMenu
union
select * from userMainMenu
```

Or you could combine the role and user anchor expressions beforehand. I don't know if the query for getting child items is generic for both role and user menu items, otherwise you could use an anchor expression that has a union for role and user root items.

```
with mainMenu (...)
as
(
    select root.* from
    (
        -- role roots
        select .. from ... and parentID is null
        union
        -- user roots
        select .. from ... and parentID is null
    ) root
    union all
    select ... from root
    inner join mainMenu on parentID = mainMenu.id
)
select *
from mainMenu
```

Comment: Great, thanks. This seems to be mostly what I'm after. The only problem now is that if the anchor has a role but the child has a user I'm not getting the user because of the inner join. I think that's my issue though. This answered my original question and I'm grateful!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the syntax that you are using with your union all. Union all is different from a join in that it combines all the rows you have selected from one table and all the rows you have selected from another table into one big table. When you do the union all, the columns that you are selecting from the various tables need to line up so sql knows how to throw all of the data into one table.

Conversely, there is the join. Unlike the union all which adds the information as more data, the join adds more information onto the same row. A join allows us to connect information together and learn more about a singular data point.

I bring both of these keywords up because you have essentially combined the syntax from union all and join. Your inner query needs a select to go with the second from and the table aliases should be removed. Your inner query should look more like this:

```
select ...
    from (
        -- role
        select ...
        from ....
            and parentID is null
        UNION
        --user
        select ...
        from ....
            and parentID is null
    )
UNION ALL
select ...
    from (
        -- role
        select ...
        from ....
            inner join  mainMenu on parentID = mainMenu.id
        UNION
        -- user
        select ...
        from ....
            inner join  mainMenu on parentID = mainMenu.id
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Jenn, I have a select in my actual code but failed to transpose it to the psudocode, I updated the OP to reflect.  As for the union all... that's how a cte recursion query is done, unless I'm missing something? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Travis, the union all looks right to me. Have you tried removing the union from inside the second subquery? I think the problem may be that you are referring to mainMenu twice.