# Default values when NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

related to this answered question I asked yesterday [Recursive query where anchor and member have unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611497/recursive-query-where-anchor-and-member-have-unions)

I have a junction table that contains

```
menuItem | roleID | userID
1        | 2      | NULL
1        | 5      | NULL
2        | NULL   | 81
```

I have a roles table

```
roleID | roleName
1      | admin
3      | super admin
5      | basic user
```

What I would like is when querying for the USERS who have access to this menu item to also include to the admin users (roleIDs `1 and 3`).  In the linked question I was able to include the admin users by including the IDs in the join clause. But because the roleID is null when including the individual users, I can't ever get the results to produce:

```
userName | menuItem
admin1   | 2
admin2   | 2
realUser | 2
```

At best i've been able to get

```
userName | menuItem
realUser | 2
realUser | 2
realUser | 2
```

How can I write this so the admin users are included as part of the result? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to join a table Users to a table Menu 
when

- The user's Role ID is 1 or 3 and the menu role id is null
- Or the userid in the user table matches the userid
- Or the users's role id matches the menu's role id

So that looks like this

```
From 
       users u
       INNER JOIN Menu m
       ON (u.RoleID in (1,3) and m.roleID  is Null)
          or u.UserId = m.userId
          or u.RoleId = m.RoleId
```