# sql recursion: find tree given middle node

Tags: t-sql

I need to get a tree of related nodes given a certain node, but not necessary top node. I've got a solution using two CTEs, since I am struggling to squeeze it all into one CTE :). Might somebody have a sleek solution to avoid using two CTEs? Here is some code that I was playing with:

```
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE (ID INT, ParentID INT)
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT 1 ID, NULL AS ParentID
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 6, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 6
UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 7

DECLARE @startNode INT = 4
;WITH TheTree (ID,ParentID)
AS (
    SELECT ID, ParentID
    FROM @temp
    WHERE ID = @startNode
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t.id, t.ParentID
    FROM @temp t
    JOIN TheTree tr ON t.ParentID = tr.ID
    )
SELECT * FROM TheTree

;WITH Up(ID,ParentID)
AS (
    SELECT t.id, t.ParentID
    FROM @temp t
    WHERE t.ID = @startNode
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t.id, t.ParentID
    FROM @temp t
    JOIN Up c ON t.id = c.ParentID
    )
    --SELECT * FROM Up
,TheTree (ID,ParentID)
AS (
    SELECT ID, ParentID
    FROM Up
    WHERE ParentID is null
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t.id, t.ParentID
    FROM @temp t
    JOIN TheTree tr ON t.ParentID = tr.ID
    )
SELECT * FROM TheTree
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meh. This avoids using two CTEs, but the result is a brute force kludge that hardly qualifies as "sleek" as it won’t be efficient if your table is at all sizeable. It will:

- Recursively build all possible hierarchies
- As you build them, flag the target NodeId as you find it
- Return only the targeted tree

I threw in column “TreeNumber” on the off-chance the TargetId appears in multiple hierarchies, or if you’d ever have multiple values to check in one pass. “Depth” was added to make the output a bit more legible.

A more complex solution like @John’s might do, and more and subtler tricks could be done with more detailed table sturctures.

```
DECLARE @startNode INT = 4

;WITH cteAllTrees (TreeNumber, Depth, ID, ParentID, ContainsTarget)
AS (
    SELECT
       row_number() over (order by ID)  TreeNumber
      ,1
      ,ID
      ,ParentID
      ,case
         when ID = @startNode then 1
         else 0
       end  ContainsTarget
     FROM @temp
     WHERE ParentId is null
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT
       tr.TreeNumber
      ,tr.Depth + 1
      ,t.id
      ,t.ParentID
      ,case
         when tr.ContainsTarget = 1 then 1
         when t.ID = @startNode then 1
         else 0
       end  ContainsTarget
    FROM @temp t
    INNER JOIN cteAllTrees tr
     ON t.ParentID = tr.ID
    )
SELECT
   TreeNumber
  ,Depth
  ,ID
  ,ParentId
 from cteAllTrees
 where TreeNumber in (select TreeNumber from cteAllTrees where ContainsTarget = 1)
 order by
   TreeNumber
  ,Depth
  ,ID
```

Comment: thanks a lot. as you said 'hardly qualifies as "sleek"' :), from performance perspective I think it is better to go with 2 CTEs. I remember professor speaking about recursion with 2 anchors (way back...) and was just hoping that someone would know about it and it would be applicable in my case.

Comment: There might be some way to wedge an `OR` clause in the recursive join, to simultaneously go up and down, but I couldn't figure out how to exclude previously-selected rows.

Comment: also tried to use algorithm presented here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611497/recursive-query-where-anchor-and-member-have-unions, but it was neither "sleek" nor efficient in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a technique where you can select the entire hierarchy, a specific node with all its children, and even a filtered list and how they roll.

Note:  See the comments next to the DECLAREs

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,pt int,name varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values 
(1,null,'1'),(2,1,'2'),(3,1,'3'),(4,2,'4'),(5,2,'5'),(6,3,'6'),(7,null,'7'),(8,7,'8')

Declare @Top    int         = null      --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 2
Declare @Nest   varchar(25) = '|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability
Declare @Filter varchar(25) = ''        --<<  Empty for All or try 4,6

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by name) as varchar(500))
            ,ID
            ,pt
            ,Lvl=1
            ,name 
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(pt,-1) else ID end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',1000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.name)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.ID
            ,r.pt
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.name 
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.pt = p.ID)
     ,cteR1 as (Select *,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteP)
     ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.ID )
Select Distinct 
       A.R1  
      ,B.R2
      ,A.ID
      ,A.pt
      ,A.Lvl
      ,name = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.name
 From cteR1 A
 Join cteR2 B on A.ID=B.ID
 Join (Select R1 From cteR1 where IIF(@Filter='',1,0)+CharIndex(concat(',',ID,','),concat(',',@Filter+','))>0) F on F.R1 between A.R1 and B.R2
 Order By A.R1
```

Comment: thanks, but it not exactly 'it'. I don't need to build a complete tree. I have a multitude of separate trees in one table (about 5 mil records) most of which are just root trees (1 node), and about 10 percent would have between 1 to 20 nodes. All I need is to find a list of nodes belonging to a tree given a node, which incidentally might be a root node, but also can be a tail or a middle node. but thanks anyway. above can be useful algorithm.